# Transact SQL - Inserting All Dates With A Specified Gap In Minutes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table of suitable rooms

```
DECLARE @tblSuitableRooms TABLE
(
    RoomID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME NULL,
    EndTime DATETIME NULL,
    RoomStartTime DATETIME NULL,
    RoomEndTime DATETIME NULL,
    RoomStartTimeCaretaker DATETIME NULL,
    RoomEndTimeCaretaker DATETIME NULL
)
```

and need to insert rows into a @tblPossiblyAvailable table

```
DECLARE @tblPossiblyAvailable TABLE
(
    RoomID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Processed BIT NOT NULL
)
```

with a gap of a fixed number of minutes (@AdvancedSearchInterval). I already have the RoomStartTimes in the table using

```
INSERT INTO @tblPossiblyAvailable
SELECT sr.RoomID, sr.RoomStartTime, 0
FROM @tblSuitableRooms sr
WHERE sr.RoomStartTime IS NOT NULL
```

but now I need to insert more records in @tblPossiblyAvailable with the StartTime between the RoomStartTime and the RoomEndTime in an interval of a certain number of minutes (AdvancedSearchInterval). This will allow me to check the availability of rooms for a day.

What I need is something like this

RoomID StartTime
1 2013-02-26 09:00:00
1 2013-02-26 09:30:00
1 2013-02-26 10:00:00
1 2013-02-26 10:30:00
1 2013-02-26 11:00:00
2 2013-02-26 08:00:00
2 2013-02-26 08:30:00
2 2013-02-26 09:00:00
2 2013-02-26 09:30:00
2 2013-02-26 10:00:00
3 2013-02-26 09:00:00
3 2013-02-26 09:30:00

I need something like a loop which says

```
insert into @tblPossiblyAvailable 
select each room from @tblSuitableRooms 
and take the start time for the room, 
then take the start time + 30 minutes and insert that with the RoomID, 
then take the last time inserted + 30 minutes and insert that with the RoomID
then take the last time inserted + 30 minutes and insert that with the RoomID
...
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Ed

P.S. I am using SQL Server 2000

This solution appears to work. Af anyone can think of a better way of going about it I would be very interested.

```
DECLARE @AdvancedSearchInterval tinyint
DECLARE @tblSuitableRooms TABLE
(
    RoomID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME NULL,
    EndTime DATETIME NULL,
    RoomStartTime DATETIME NULL,
    RoomEndTime DATETIME NULL,
    RoomStartTimeCaretaker DATETIME NULL,
    RoomEndTimeCaretaker DATETIME NULL
)
DECLARE @tblPossiblyAvailable TABLE
(
    RoomID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Processed BIT NOT NULL
)

SET @AdvancedSearchInterval = 30

INSERT INTO @tblSuitableRooms
select 1, getdate(), getdate(), '2013-02-26 08:00:00', '2013-02-26 17:00:00', getdate(), getdate()
UNION ALL
select 2, getdate(), getdate(), '2013-02-26 10:00:00', '2013-02-26 19:00:00', getdate(), getdate()
UNION ALL
select 3, getdate(), getdate(), '2013-02-26 09:00:00', '2013-02-26 17:00:00', getdate(), getdate()

DECLARE @mins INT
SET @mins = 0
WHILE @mins < 1440
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @tblPossiblyAvailable
    SELECT RoomID, DATEADD(MINUTE,@mins,RoomStartTime), 0
    FROM @tblSuitableRooms
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE,@mins,RoomStartTime) < RoomEndTime

    SET @mins = @mins + @AdvancedSearchInterval
END

SELECT *
FROM @tblPossiblyAvailable
ORDER BY StartTime
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest alternative solutions for MS SQL 2000 without using loops:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SearchInterval TINYINT
SELECT @SearchInterval = 30

DECLARE @SuitableRooms TABLE 
(
      RoomID BIGINT
    , RoomStartTime DATETIME
    , RoomEndTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @SuitableRooms (RoomID, RoomStartTime, RoomEndTime) 
SELECT 1, '2013-02-26 08:00:00', '2013-02-26 17:00:00'
  UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2013-02-26 10:00:00', '2013-02-26 19:00:00'
  UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '2013-02-26 09:00:00', '2013-02-26 17:00:00'

DECLARE @emun TABLE (i BIGINT IDENTITY, blank BIT)
INSERT INTO @emun (blank)
SELECT 1
FROM [master].dbo.spt_values n
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT i = 1 
      UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 
) b

SELECT r.RoomID, StartTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, i, RoomStartTime)
FROM (
    SELECT i = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT i
    FROM @emun
    WHERE i % @SearchInterval = 0
) d
CROSS JOIN @SuitableRooms r
WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, i, RoomStartTime) < RoomEndTime
ORDER BY StartTime
```

For MS SQL versions > 2000 (very sad that MS SQL 2000 does not support CTE):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SearchInterval TINYINT
SELECT @SearchInterval = 30

;WITH emun AS 
(
    SELECT  
          RoomID
        , StartTime
        , EndTime
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              RoomID = 1
            , StartTime = CAST('2013-02-26 08:00:00' AS DATETIME)
            , EndTime = '2013-02-26 17:00:00'

          UNION ALL

        SELECT 2, '2013-02-26 10:00:00', '2013-02-26 19:00:00'
          UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, '2013-02-26 09:00:00', '2013-02-26 17:00:00'
    ) d

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  
          RoomID
        , StartTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, @SearchInterval, StartTime)
        , EndTime
    FROM emun
    WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, @SearchInterval, StartTime) < EndTime
)

SELECT RoomID, StartTime
FROM emun
ORDER BY StartTime
```